# Fountain of Wealth

Tags: word, knowledge, cryptic-crosswords

Based on the following crossword, find a word to describe those with fancy titles and lots of money.

[image: crossword grid, transcribed at bottom of question]

| Across | Down |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Clear area for brightest star in constellation (6) | 1. Refuse time off once at university regarding studies (10) |
| 4. Paper printed a picture originally with topless Miley (7) | 2. Eric, our new messenger (7) |
| 9. Crazy aunts starting to make me wave (7) | 3. Loud engine fad exploding (9) |
| 10. French future is vainer, surprisingly (6) | 5. Silver corroded sulfur rock formations (6) |
| 11. Harp on about charge added to ceremony right away (9)* | 6. Submit income (5) |
| 12. Drag race led by director (4) | 7. You left after it brought up extent (not small) of exercise (7) |
| 14. Final word in a lesson's introduction (8) | 8. Programming language inspired by CICS has bugs (7) |
| 15. Uniting believers (originally leaderless), religion offers omnipresence (6)** | 13. Compositor likes early transcriptions to begin with detailed title (10) |
| 18. Quit golf, drawn in by pitch (6) | 16. Wilt Chamberlain's Plough (3,6) |
| 20. House party near Nathan's stand (8) | 17. Pattern stone with lead-free pencil (7) |
| 23. Learner put in beginner's league (4) | 19. Welsh foundation for fashion: AnySelf (7) |
| 25. Guardian of the Galaxy cut heart of monster (9) | 21. Jack Sheen denied lead in Obliterate (7) |
| 26. Rainier Mountain Hotel, surrounded by a ditch, making a comeback? (6) | 22. Mark from demon work (6) |
| 27. One million run in unit track (7) | 24. Life near Maine's ecosystem (5) |
| 28. Bugs in programming language limited by arrays (7) |  |
| 29. Arkansas singer Bowman (6) |  |

Clues were originally:

> *Harp on about charge added to incomplete ceremony (9)

> **Uniting believers (originally leaderless), god offers omnipresence (6)

### Markdown Transcription

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | _ | 2 | _ | 3 | _ | ■ | 4 | 5 | _ | 6 | _ | 7 | _ | ■ |
| _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | 8 | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | ■ |
| 9 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | ■ | 10 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | ■ |
| _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | ■ |
| 11 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | ■ | 12 | _ | _ | _ | ■ |
| _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | ■ | ■ | _ | ■ | 13 |
| 14 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | ■ | 15 | 16 | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| _ | ■ | ■ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | 17 | ■ | _ | ■ | ■ | ■ | _ |
| 18 | _ | 19 | _ | _ | _ | ■ | 20 | _ | _ | _ | _ | 21 | _ | _ |
| _ | ■ | _ | ■ | ■ | ■ | 22 | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ |
| ■ | 23 | _ | _ | 24 | ■ | 25 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| ■ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ |
| ■ | 26 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | ■ | 27 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |
| ■ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ | ■ | _ |
| ■ | 28 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ | ■ | 29 | _ | _ | _ | _ | _ |

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

In the grid, there are

> a few odd clue answers. As hinted by the two long down entries (LITERATURE and TYPESETTER), many of the entries are font names!

Specifically:

> LUCIDA, PAPYRUS, AVENIR, TERMINAL, TAHOMA, IMPRINT, ARCHER, COURIER, STENCIL, SYLFAEN, and IMPACT are all fonts.
>
>  The first letters of these anagram to **CAPITALISTS**, a word that could certainly describe people with either fancy titles or lots of money!
>
>  (And as a bonus, "fountain" in the title hints at a different, though related, meaning of the word "font".)